# GIF with position:absolute not playing in Android Webview

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an Android app using [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org). I have a GIF preloader, but when I set it's position to absolute, it stops "playing", appearing to be frozen.

When I remove position:absolute it works fine.
I've tested on Android 2.3.3. Is there a known bug or am I missing something?

```
<img src="img/preloader.gif" style="position:absolute" />
```

or

```
<img src="img/preloader.gif" class="preloader" />

<style>
.preloader{
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

The same happens with position:relative.

Comment: is ur gif image too heavy?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Just 8,4KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by wraping the image in a div and applying the position:absolute to the div. Worked fine!

```
<div style="position:absolute">
    <img src="img/preloader.gif" />
</div>
```